# can bash on windows10 execute windows programs?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, bash

I'm excited about the possibility of having a decent command-line interface on MS Windows using bash, I haven't installed windows10 yet though. In bash in windows would I be able to run windows command-line programs by calling them in bash?

Could I tell bash to run a windows program?

Comment: You should update your question to make it clear your using a Insider Preview of what will be Version 1608. Worth pointing out that Bash in general cannot launch Windows programs.  Bash is only available to the `Ubuntu on Windows` environment.

Comment: @Ramhound. "Bash is only available to the Ubuntu on Windows environment": Correction - or cygwin, gitbash, msys, ... all of which **will** run Windows programs.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I suppose in the context, of programs like Cygwin, my second setence is incorrect.  In the context of this question, I presume the author is talking about the `Ubtunu on Windows` feature.

Comment: like 3 years ago, I knew a guy who installed bash on XP, and got that mad functionality in Windowz CMD. I thought bash as a CLI on windows would offer that. Im looking now at cygwin.

Comment: If someone wants to post Use cygwin, it'll do what you want, I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 3):

I have not personally installed it, but taking an excerpt from this article, it looks like no:

> Remember, software you install in the Bash shell is restricted to the Bash shell. You can’t access it from the Command Prompt, PowerShell, or elsewhere in Windows. Software in the Bash shell also can’t interact directly with or launch Windows programs, although the Bash environment and Windows have access to the same files on your computer.

Full article available below:
http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/